# Remove Order from Deny Allow Directive Apache Linux

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

Can I remove the Order deny, allow directive  because the Deny and Allow directives are in the correct order?  Or do I need to keep Order no matter what.

```
Deny from 2.8 2.9
Allow from all
Order deny,allow
```

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for explaining config file problems, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: _“because the Deny and Allow directives are in the correct order”_ - you mean via inheritance from the upper directories/central server configuration? The configuration at those upper levels could change at any time, and so your local configuration in this place would change with it. Whether you’d _want_ that, is for you to decide. Probably rather not, because that could easily disable this by accident.